# What is the order of $\mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Find the order of $\mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2}$?

I know there is this rule which says you multiple 2 $\times$ 2 to get the order however, it does not apply in this case because the $\gcd(2,2) \neq1$ but rather $2$. so the order is $2$?

Even if I wanted to do this explicitly, I can't find a generator that has order $4$, the max I found was order $2$ which are the elements $(1,1), (0,1)$ and $(1,0).$

Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be confused on the definition of "order" of a group. It simply means the number of elements. The relation between this and the "order" of an element is that the order of $a\in G$ is the order of the subgroup generated by $a$.

There is a term called the "exponent" of a group, which means the least common multiple of the orders of the individual elements.

Answer (score 4):

$\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$

i.e Cartesian product of the set $\{0,1\}$ with itself

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ and $H$ are finite, then:

$|G \times H| = |G|\cdot|H|$.

Sketch of proof: for each element $(g,h) \in G\times H$, we have $|G|$ choices for $g$, and $|H|$ choices for $h$.